# scala: how to cross build the library dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, scala-gatling

i am using `scala 2.13` and i have to use [Gatling load tests](https://gatling.io/docs/current), Gatling does not support `Scala-2.13` for that i looked into [sbt cross build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html) and [how to cross build library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403305/in-sbt-how-can-i-cross-build-with-dependencies-that-are-not-required-in-one-ver) 
i have two Gatling dependencies

```
"io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.3.1",
    "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.3.1"
```

these libraries support `Scala 2.12` for that i am doing something like this
build.sbt

```
lazy val scala212 = "2.12.10"

lazy val scala213 = "2.13.1"

scalaVersion := scala213

lazy val supportedScalaVersions = List(scala213, scala212)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions,
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.8.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.3"
)

libraryDependencies ++= (scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
  case "2.12.10" => Seq(
    "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.3.1",
    "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.3.1"
  )
  case _ => Seq()
}
  )
```

`Sbt` is not downloading the Gatling dependencies and `sbt update` command does not show any error it looks like the `case 2.12.10 match` part is not even executed

what is the right way to do this ? i want to write Gatling simulations in test directory

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost right but `scalaBinaryVersion` is `2.12` in your case. `scalaVersion.value` is what you are looking for.